# File upload validation by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to restrict a file upload control to allow PDF files only. I want to use JavaScript for that.

I want to apply that JavaScript in file upload event.

Comment: All doable, but don't forget to validate on server side as well since JS can be disabled/spoofed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the file name on submit.

```
"hook to the <form>'s onsubmit with whatever method" {
  filename = theFileElement.value;
  if (!/\.pdf$/i.test(filename)) {
    alert("error");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Note that this only checks if the file has an extension of `.pdf`. It **does not** (and cannot) check whether the file is really a just PDF or actually a nasty virus. Moreover, client side Javascript can easily be bypassed, so you should perform the check again on the server side.

Comment: There are some APIs in modern releases of Firefox (and maybe the WebKit browsers) that allow some inspection of files.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: @Pointy: True, but you can't deny users from using IE.

Comment: Of course; the point is that it's not absolutely impossible for the client to examine files being uploaded, and eventually even IE will have that ability.  (We may be long dead by then, of course.)

Comment: @KennyTM Now how can i check with two type of formats like `pdf` and `doc` at a time

Comment: @Rafee `if(!/(\.txt|\.pdf|\.exls|\.doc)$/i.test(document.formname.field))`  It will restrict these types of documents.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ext = fname.split(".");
var x=ext.length;
if(ext[x-1] == 'pdf'){
  alert("Please upload doc file");
  document.form.fname.focus();
  return false;
}
```